# Printing out double with variable length after decimal point

Tags: java

I was searching for a solution of how to print double with variable length. Means: user will define how many digits he wants after the decimal point, but without success.
I've come to something like, but it doesn't work :

num - double

dec(length) - integer

`System.out.printf("%.(%d)f\n", num, dec);`

Comment: `System.out.printf("%." + dec + "f%n", num);`

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following?
Maybe solution 2 is suitable for you.

Solution 1:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", val); // "%.2f" it's a string so you can make it in several ways...eg: "%."+ dec + "f";
```

Solution 2:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); // you can use int variable instead of 2.. eg: df.setMaximumFractionDigits(dec);
System.out.println(df.format(decimalNumber));
```